# What is the correct syntax for a Regex find-and-replace using REGEXP_REPLACE in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, regex, pcre, mariadb

I need to run a regex find-and-replace against a column named `message` in a MySQL table named `post`.

My database is running MariaDB 10.

According to the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/functions-and-operators/string-functions/regular-expressions-functions/regexp_replace/), MariaDB 10 has a new `REGEXP_REPLACE` function designed to do exactly this, but I can't seem to figure out the actual syntax.

It will affect 280,000 rows, so ideally there's also a way to limit it to only changing one specific row at a time while I'm testing it, or simply doing a `SELECT` rather than an `UPDATE` until I'm sure it does what I want.

The regex I want to run:
`\[quote\sauthor=(.+)\slink=[^\]]+]`

The replacement string: 
`[quote="$1"]`

The following was what I tried, but it just throws a SQL error:

`UPDATE post SET message = REGEXP_REPLACE(message, '\[quote\sauthor=(.+)\slink=[^\]]+]', '[quote="$1"]')  WHERE post_id = 12`

In this case, the original message was:
`[quote author=Jon_doe link=board=2;threadid=125;start=40#msg1206 date=1065088]` and the end result should be `[quote="Jon_doe"]`

What is the proper syntax to make this `REGEXP_REPLACE` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do a lot of escaping here:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(message, "\\[quote\\sauthor=(.+)\\slink=[^\\]]+]", "\\[quote=\"\\1\"\\]")
```

Please note that you have to reference the Group by `\\1`

Comment: So in MySQL's flavor of regex an escape is '\\' rather than '\'?

I was testing this regex in a few online tools with just the '\' and they were all treating that as valid

Comment: \ will escape something in SQL. But if you want to pass a \ to the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function you have to escape the escap-Symbol...

Comment: Where did `name` come from?