# regex capture group in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-group

Is it possible to capture the regex match in the select part of the query in mysql?

I'd like to query for an initial letters in the UK postcode like:

`SELECT all initiall letters from a post code (one or two) FROM addresses;`

UK postcodes start with one or two letters and then have one or two digits, optional space, then two letters and finally a digit.

Examples:

SW8 4EX

E1 7AG

EC1 8AG

SE17 9AW

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please provide examples. Perhaps, have a look at [What is the correct syntax for a Regex find-and-replace using REGEXP_REPLACE in MariaDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498929/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-a-regex-find-and-replace-using-regexp-replace-in).

Comment: this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function

Comment: @pcantalupo that post is about Sql Server ...

Comment: What's the content of the addresses column? can you post some sample data? It might be just a `SUBSTRING(addresses, 0, 2)`.

Comment: @solarc I've added some examples of UK postcodes

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('SW8 4EX', ' .*', '');
```

This should work with your examples. 
First make sure the postcode column does not contain leading space.